# Anyone have experience with Silicon Mechanics 4-Node Machines?

Tags: hardware, rackmount, blade-server

I'm taking a look at buying some new servers (small infrastructure, 2 racks, etc), and although I like a lot of the features in blades, I'm looking at the price point for Silicon Mechanics' 4-node machines.

http://www.siliconmechanics.com/i27091/xeon-2U-4-Node.php

It's a bit like a mini-blade enclosure, but has no shared resources, except for the redundant power supplies. A single point of management would be great, but for the low price point here, I'm possibly willing to give that up, if the server quality is adequate.

Basically, have you used these machines? Any problems? Anything you like?

Comment: not specifically with this model, but I know folks who swear-by Silicon Mechanics